# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Mathematica's [third moderator election](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: halirutan]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5652369241014272/0).

Comment: thank you for your service 8)

Answer (score 31):

It seems not custom that the newly elected says some words but I will do it anyway. I thank everyone who voted for their trust and I will do my best to help the community.

This is my first night as a moderator and as you all can imagine I'm quite anxious. I double-check every mouse click I do, always afraid to accidentally delete our beloved site. I'm sure this will pass in the upcoming weeks when I finally get used to everything.

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to the team!

Comment: Almost everything you do can be undone. Almost. ;-)

Comment: @Jon Ericson ... the unfortunate possibility for all kinds of "creators". ;-)

Comment: Congrats Halirutan!

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the work you put into the community.

Comment: Congratulations Halirutan!

Comment: Thank you all for your compliments.